# iOS counting app with calculations

Tags: ios, ios-appstore

I am looking for an iOS app that works like a simple counter but also does simple calculations like running averages. There is an android app called multicounter but I have not found an iOS equivalent. Basically I need to clickable counter for errors and success rate. success count/(error+success)

Comment: I looked on the ioS app store and searched on conters. I found about 20 but couldn't find one with the option you neeeded. You may wih to look at these youself. Most were free.

Comment: I found several counters but also could not find one I could use for a real time average.

Comment: Hey There, Welcome to Ask Different! You could write a shortcut for that and add it to your home screen. There is an option for average in statistics operations. Also counter is there too. Have a look and edit/ ask a new question for improvements in shortcut.

Comment: I take it you are looking for a time averge of clicks, for example.  Number of clicks per second.